# keep getting error when trying to output data in spring,hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi im currently new to hibernate and im using it with Spring framework, im getting an error that i can't figure it out.I think it's in my Service or my DAO file

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error Type Exception Report
>
> message Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from satisfying the request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError
>   (DispatcherServlet.java:1284)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch
>   (DispatcherServlet.java:965)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService
>   (DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest
>   (FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet
>   (FrameworkServlet.java:852)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
>   (HttpServlet.java:634)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service
>   (FrameworkServlet.java:837)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
>   (HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter
>   (WsFilter.java:53) mother cause
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     util.HibernateUtil. 
>   (HibernateUtil.java:29)   DAO.RoomDAO.getAllroom (RoomDAO.java:19)
>     service.RoomService.getAllroom (RoomService.java:21)
>     controller.HomepageController.roomlist
>   (HomepageController.java:31)
>   my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- declaring base package -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
     <context:component-scan base-package="org.jasig.portlet" />
    <!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="rDAO" class="DAO.RoomDAO" />
    <bean id="rService" class="service.RoomService" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <hibernate-configuration>   <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
         <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="model/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="model/Calendars.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="model/Notifications.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="model/Room.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="model/NotificationEvents.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="model/Events.hbm.xml"/>   </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```

my RoomDAO file

```
> public class RoomDAO {
>     public ArrayList<Room> getAllroom(){
>      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
>      Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
>      Query query = (Query)session.createQuery("from room");
>      ArrayList<Room> list = (ArrayList<Room>) query.list();
>      transaction.commit();
>      return list; }
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println(new RoomDAO().getAllroom().size());
>     } }
```

my homepagecontroller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public class HomepageController {
    @Autowired
    RoomService roomservice;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String index(ModelMap mm){
        return "jsp/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/roomlist")
    public String roomlist(ModelMap mm){
        mm.put("listRoom",roomservice.getAllroom());
        return "jsp/roomlist";
    }
}
```

my RoomService.java

```
public class RoomService {
    @Autowired
    RoomDAO RoomDAO;
    public ArrayList<Room> getAllroom(){
        return RoomDAO.getAllroom();
    }
}
```

my web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

any the data that i want to output in my JSP file

```
 <tr>
                  <c:forEach var="room" items="${listRoom}">
                    <th scope="row"><c:out value="${room.room_id}"/></th>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">${room.room_name}
                        </button>
                      </td>
                      <td><c:out value="${room.address}"/></td>
                      <td><c:out value="${room.description}"/></td>
                      <td><c:out value="${room.device}"/></td>
                      <td>
                        <a href="add_room.html" title=""><label class="btn btn-xs btn-success margin-top-1"><span class="fa fa-plus-square" title="add"></span></label></a>
                        <a href="edit_room.html" title=""><label class="btn btn-xs btn-info margin-top-1"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" title="edit"></span></label></a>
                        <label class="btn btn-xs btn-danger margin-top-1"><span class="fa fa-times" title="Cancel"></span></label>
                       </td>
                    </c:forEach>

                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Application context initialization is failed. There will be several reasons for this failure. Please push code to github and share the link.

Have you configured DispatcherServlet in web.xml?

Have you added contextConfigLocation for dispaycher-servlet xml file in web.xml?

Verify whether hibernate.cg.xml is loading or not?

Comment: yeah i did <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: also the hibernate.cfg.xml running because i ran the template only and it worked. i get the error when i try to output data from database